# Why use ^[\s\u200c]+|[\s\u200c]+$ to trim spaces?

Tags: regex

I came across some code [recently](http://stackstatus.net/post/147710624694/outage-postmortem-july-20-2016) where the following regex was being used to trim spaces (and `\u200c`) from the start and end of a string.

Is there a good reason to use a regex, or can I replace it with a `trim()` function?

Comment: Looks like SO replaced it with substring. I assume because it appears that the string in question started with characters, contained thousands of spaces, and then had different characters afterwards. So, trim() might not be ideal.

Comment: "Where the following regex was used" You didn't follow with a regex.

Comment: To trim "spaces", you only need `^\s+|\s+$` (or `trim`), you do not need to also use the [zero-width joiner](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) that belongs to *Category: Other, Format `[Cf]`*. The question is based on a wrong assumption.

Comment: Thank you for taking [SO down](http://stackstatus.net/post/147710624694/outage-postmortem-july-20-2016)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\u200c` is the [zero width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) character, which `trim()` does not consider whitespace ([at least in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--)).  You should probably use `trim()` unless you expect zero width non-joiner characters at the beginning or end of your input and you want to remove them - apparently StackOverflow does have this requirement.

Comment: Usually `trim()` functions accept an argument to specify the characters to remove, maybe this isn't the case though.

Comment: You're right - Stack Overflow is [most likely using C#](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/), which has a [`trim(char[])` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp).  I can't think of any reason that a regex would be superior to using that method for this use case.